# LaTeX causes Anki to crash

Tags: texlive, anki

I'm attempting to use LaTeX along with anki to enhance the typsetting system in anki.

The issue I run into that some cards simply crash the anki application for no apparent reason.

Here is how I customized my card type to enable LaTeX:

```
[latex]{{Front}}[/latex]
```

And

```
{{FrontSide}}
<div class="source">{{Source}}</div>
[latex]{{Back}}[/latex]
```

Cards like this work well: [image: Sample card that doesn't crash the app.]

Cards like this however crash the applictaion: [image: Sample card that does crash the app]

Comment: It seems like this should rather be reported to the Anki maintainers instead of here.

Comment: I'm not sure if the problem is with latex or anki (because some cards do work well), so I'm doing both and looking for the users who use both to aid me.

Comment: You provide too little information to analyze the problem. My Anki does not crash if I mimick your cards, except that Anki complains about `source` being an unknown field. At a minimum, give operating system, Anki version, steps to reproduce the problem, and the error message you get ("crash" is very general).

Comment: The probablem Is that I don't know why these cards crash in the first place. Some of them work fine.